# Where is the winget downloaded exe go?

Tags: windows, terminal

ITNOA

As you can see [Where do downloaded .exe files go?](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/discussions/1148) ask

When I run something like winget install vlc it downloads vlc.exe but where is it saved?

I downloaded a large installer file with winget but the installation failed because my computer was locked when the UAC screen appeared and I just got an error in powershell (this should be fixed).

I'd prefer not to download it again but to use the downloaded exe file.

Please tell me where exactly it is saved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [JohnMcPMS](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/discussions/1148#discussioncomment-855120)

Currently the file ends up here:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TempState\WinGet`

but if anyone finds this in the future (post 1.0 builds), we are moving it to just be in:

`%TEMP%\WinGet`

I just to reanswer this question to this Q&A site for better finding by Bing and Google